# Want to set GRE as the default network

Tags: ip, route, tunneling, gre

I have configured 2 servers, SERVER A and SERVER B. (I have followed this tutorial: https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/linux-setup-gre-tunnel)

I have used SERVER A for GRE tunnel to SERVER B (Meaning all traffic sent to server A shall be routed to Server B and served from there only).
What I wish to do now is when I use "curl ip.me" on terminal of SERVER A, it shows me the IP of Server B, I want it to use the Public IPv4 address of SERVER A only, so that it routes all the traffic to server B only, (much like what happens when I do "curl ip.me --interface 10.0.0.2".

So my question is how do I make the interface 10.0.0.2 default for all outgoing traffic from my server without the need to specify it on the command at all?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

Let's establish the following concrete addressing scheme (since you didn't provided any):

- **Server `A`**:

  - `eno1`: address `198.51.100.2/24`, gateway `198.51.100.1`
  - `gre1`: remote `192.0.2.2`, local `198.51.100.2`, address `10.0.0.1/30`
- **Server `B`**:

  - `eno1`: `192.0.2.2/24`, gateway `192.0.2.1`
  - `gre1`: remote `198.51.100.2`, local `192.0.2.2`, address `10.0.0.2/30`

Notice that local and remote properties of GRE interfaces are mirror of each other, and their addresses belong to the same /30 subnet. In this case (if everything else is set up properly, e.g. firewalls, IPsec, etc.) servers will be able to ping each other through the tunnel by using `10.0.0.x` addresses. On the physical network you will observe the GRE traffic between their public IP addresses, `198.51.100.2` and `192.0.2.2`.

Routes on the server `B` are currently like this:

```
default via 192.0.2.1
192.0.2.0/24 dev eno1 src 192.0.2.2
10.0.0.0/30 dev gre1 src 192.0.2.2
```

You only need that `192.0.2.1` is used (directly) to support GRE and nothing more, and everything else is to be routed via GRE tunnel. This could be done by adding a route towards the `A` `198.51.100.2` through the former gateway, and setting `A`'s GRE address as the new gateway. The routing table on `B` becomes:

```
default via 10.0.0.1
198.51.100.2 via 192.0.2.1
192.0.2.0/24 dev eno1 src 192.0.2.2
10.0.0.0/30 dev gre1 src 192.0.2.2
```

For server `B` to able to reach Internet now you need to source-NAT it on the host `A`, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.2 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
```

And, if there are services on the `B` that you want to publish, you need to destination-NAT them on `A`, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
```

The host `B` will be accessible directly from only host `A` and hosts in its "local" network, which is `192.0.2.0/24` in this case. All other hosts will see its traffic as coming from `A` with address `198.51.100.2` and, if they wish to use any published services, they need to communicate to `A`.

It is possible to make B directly accessible too, to force even hosts in its local network to go through A and otherwise augment the system, but that requires much more complicated setup, involving policy routing and finer firewall settings.

Also I must advise you against using plain GRE (and against using GRE at all). It is completely unprotected per se, so at least you must accompany it with IPsec (in transport mode between `A` and `B`). It will still struggle to work from behind the NAT. Better and much simpler is to replace it with WireGuard, the routing setup will stay the same regardless of the tunnel technology you use. OpenVPN is easiest, because it even has the provision to build this exact configuration *automatically* once tunnel is established, for which you need `A` to be the server and `B` to be the client — if enabled, during connection establishment it will determine the "former" gateway and add direct route to the VPN server, then replace the default route with tunnel endpoint, achieving the described routing setup. A disadvantage of OpenVPN against WireGuard is much lower performance.

Comment: Comment to Nikita Kipriyanov: with "making `b` directly accessible" you mean `192.0.2.2/24` will be directly accessible even when default route is via the GRE tunnel? Could you explain more about this?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_routing#Routing_algorithm)'s the algorithm. Addresses within this network all match the first "if" condition.

Answer (score -2):

Being simple - you can't, because tunnel interface is subordinate to a physical: it needs the tunnel source from it's parent.

Comment: Just another "smarty" comment from me: there is no such thing as "parent" interface for GRE. it will route its packets against the respective routing table, whichever interface that selects. Also, see the other answer — it's overall possible and *widely used* with OpenVPN, but easy to build the same thing with any other tunneling technology (except naked IPsec whose tunneling is special).